# How do I install HHVM 3.30 with its source code?

Tags: hhvm

I need to install version HHVM 3.30 with its source code.
But when I get to the step of executing the git submodule update --init --recursive instructions for installation, I get the following error and this happens before Make.

> fatal: unable to access 'https://scm.gforge.inria.fr/anonscm/git/cudf/cudf.git/': gnutls_handshake() failed: Error in the pull function.
> fatal: clone of 'https://scm.gforge.inria.fr/anonscm/git/cudf/cudf.git' into submodule path '/home/zahra/hhvm/third-party/ocaml/opam_deps/cudf' failed
> Failed to clone 'ocaml/opam_deps/cudf' a second time, aborting
> Failed to recurse into submodule path 'third-party'

Steps:

```
git clone https://github.com/facebook/hhvm.git \
    && cd hhvm \
    && git checkout HHVM-3.30 \
    && git submodule update --init --recursive \
    && cmake -DMYSQL_UNIX_SOCK_ADDR=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock . \
    && make -j $(nproc) \
    && make install \
    && cd .. && rm -rf /hhvm
```

please guide me.
Thanks

Comment: Please please don't use such an ancient version of HHVM. Version 3.30 has been [out of support for *more than two and a half years*](https://hhvm.com/blog/2018/12/17/hhvm-3.30.html). It has multiple known remotely-exploitable security issues. You are probably using it for its PHP support (which was dropped after 3.30) -- you should migrate to a supported version of the standard php.net runtime instead. Seriously, *you are leaving your users at massive risk if you continue to use HHVM 3.30*.

Answer (score 0):

The github issue you created had the solution: the hhvm version is unsupported and the remote server with the submodules may have shut down.

Source: https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/9105#issuecomment-1153508340